# custom theme creation error in magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento, magento2.4

when  run, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f command then it's giving error like below

Error happened during deploy process: Deprecated Functionality: pathinfo(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver.php on line 44

is there any solution for this.
thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we must put the logo.png image file in our theme:

app/design/frontend/[our_vendor]/[theme]/web/images/logo.png